# Django i18n and caching interference

Tags: django, caching, internationalization

I realize that this is a known [problem](http://python.6.n6.nabble.com/Internationalization-and-caching-not-working-td84364.html), [problem](http://www.mail-archive.com/django-users@googlegroups.com/msg63780.html) but I still have not found and adequate solution.

I want to use the @cache_page for a some views in my Django apps, like so:

```
@cache_page(24 * 60 * 60)
def some_view(request):
    ...
```

The problem is that I am also using i18n with a language switcher to switch languages of each page. So, if I turn on the caching I do not get the results I expect. It seems I get whatever was the last cached page.

I have tried this:

```
@cache_page(24 * 60 * 60)
@vary_on_headers('Content-Language', 'Accept-Language') 
def some_view(request):
    ...
```

**EDIT** ...and this:

```
@cache_page(24 * 60 * 60)
@vary_on_cookie 
def some_view(request):
    ...
```

**END EDIT**

But I get the same results.

Of course, if I remove the caching everything works as expected.

Any help would be MUCH appreciated.

Comment: The language setting is often stored in cookie. Did you try \@vary_on_cookie ? Or you might need a custom \@vary decorator..

Comment: Yes I have tried `@vary_on_cookie`. Same result. I cannot believe this a problem without a simple solution. Using cache + i18n surely can't be uncommon?

Comment: I've just made a little test. For me it seems that caching works as expected. It is also described in the Django docs, that in case when USE_I18N = True and USE_L10N = True, the locale id is appended to the cache key. So, can you describe what exactly happens - what http headers do you receive when trying to load a page, which is cached, and after changing the locale? Is it loaded from local browser's Cache? Is there a 302/Not Modified header returned by the server? Which Django version do you use?

Comment: Yes, the cache key seem to be constructed properly: `:1:views.decorators.cache.cache_header...en-us` and `1:views.decorators.cache.cache_header....es`. Looking at the headers, it seems that `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: en-us,en;q=0.5` is ALWAYS returned regardless of the locale. In chrome, switching off the `@cache_page` allows it to function as expected. I tried a different browser (FF instead of Chrome) and the locale switching works as normal, although the `en-us` header is still always returned.

Comment: Ok - another weird thing is: in FF the page seems to load from cache AND dynamically. In FF I can see that all variables (like 15 queries) are loaded from the db as though the cache is not being used, though there are the two expected queries for the cache ASWELL. This is so strange.

Comment: OK - this seems like it may be more of a Browser-caching issue that a Django issue :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - there seemed to be issues with the browser cache and not with Django itself. I have since found it useful to turn off all browser caching in development (seems obvious I know).

Answer (score 0):

On django 1.10 language is handled by the decorator

The code at django.utils -> cache.py has method _generate_cache_key which returns as return **_i18n_cache_key_suffix**(request, cache_key)

If we look into that it accomodates the language setting.